# Contact Form 7 to CSV whitout column title

Tags: wordpress, csv, contact-form-7

I'm looking for a plugin that allows me to download completed forms in CSV, I found several but when I download the CSV, the column titles bother me, I would also like to be able to remove the column IDs.

Here's what I get when someone signs up:

[image]

Does anyone know how I could do with form7 to download all the entries with only the data without the column names and without the ID, Date and Status columns?

Merci !